# Add a new option to select on click of "Other" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

On choosing "Other", input box should appear whose value will be appended to  as an

After adding the new option, "Other" should still be there in the dropdown. How to achieve this?

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
   <option>Notification</option>
   <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

Input box:

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

After you add value "Alert" as an option, this should be the  structure,

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
       <option>Notification</option>
       <option>Alert</option>
       <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What code have you written to complete this task? At the moment the question is more of a 'write my code for me' request which is likely to be downvoted and/or closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for you. First change option's text by your input value and after add new option with the text "Other".

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
    if($('#new-option').val() != '')
    {
        var val = $('#new-option').val();
        $('#foo option:last').html(val);
        var opt = '<option>Other</option>';
        $('#foo').append(opt);
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="foo">
  <option>Notification</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="new-option" required>
<button type="button" id="add">Add Option</button>
```